# Hide and Show on hover in the same div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hover

This is the html part:

```
<div class ="row respect-row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <h2 id ="respect-hover">RESPECT</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class ="row respect-row-hidden">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h2 id ="respect-hover">RESPECT</h2>
                    <p id="hidden-respect-paragraph">&#8221;Respect yourself and others will<br> respect you.&#8221; &#8212; Confucius</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is the jquery part:

```
$(".respect-row").hover(function(){
                $(this).hide();
                $(".respect-row-hidden").show();
            },function(){
                $(this).show();
                $(".respect-row-hidden").hide();
        });
```

My problem is that on hover in or out sometimes it gets stucked. The class **respect-row** and **respect-row-hidden** positions are the same in the page. Even when I'm on the text **Confucius** it hovers out. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID should be `unique`. so i have changed the duplicate ids into class. Additionally we need to use `multiple selector` in this context to avoid that flickering.

HTML:

```
<div class="row respect-row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <h2 class="respect-hover">RESPECT</h2>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row respect-row-hidden">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         <h2 class="respect-hover">RESPECT</h2>

        <p id="hidden-respect-paragraph">&#8221;Respect yourself and others will
            <br>respect you.&#8221; &#8212; Confucius</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".respect-row,.respect-hover").hover(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".respect-row-hidden").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).show();
    $(".respect-row-hidden").hide();
});
```

CSS:

```
.respect-row-hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/djzok1o5/)

Answer (score 0):

**try this..**

```
HTML:
    <div class ="row respect-row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <h2 id ="respect-hover">RESPECT</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="row respect-row-hidden">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h2 id ="respect-hover">RESPECT</h2>
    <p id="hidden-respect-paragraph">Respect yourself and others will respect you.&#8221; &#8212; Confucius</p>
                        </div>
                </div>

 Jquery:

    $( ".respect-row" )
      .on( "mouseenter", function() {
        $( ".respect-row" ).hide();
                    $(".respect-row-hidden").show();
      })
      .on( "mouseleave", function() {
        $( ".respect-row" ).show();
                    $(".respect-row-hidden").hide();
      });

CSS:

.respect-row-hidden {

    display:none;

}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/29f6k2ut/1/